# Implementing a Point and Click Web Data Extractor

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I have built a web crawler using jsoup. In the current version, the users have to use Firefinder to enter CSS selector.

I wanted to simplify this so that users who aren't aware of CSS can also use my tool. I found this tool http://www.mozenda.com and saw that they have a point and click interface for selecting a particular element in a web page.

How do I implement such a interface? Or is there any other way through which I can make it simple for the user to give input to my engine?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/144991) to do this point- and clicking.

You can look in the source, to see how it is done (Capturing the document mouseup event and then using window.getSelection to get the element)